# DZNEmptyDataSet not compatible with tableview binding in RxSwift. Was anyone able to make it work?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I'm trying to set up an empty dataset with DZNEmptyDataSet while my tableview is bound to an Rx variable

```
let Chats = Variable(Section).

Chats.asObservable()

    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
```

and my dzn code is as follows:

```
tableView.emptyDataSetSource = self
tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = self


func title(forEmptyDataSet scrollView: UIScrollView) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let str = "Welcome"
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline)]
    return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attrs)
}

func description(forEmptyDataSet scrollView: UIScrollView) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let str = "Tap the button below to add your first grokkleglob."
    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.body)]
    return NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: attrs)
}
```

The problem is, even when Chats is empty, the empty dataSet for the tableview doesn't show. If i remove the bind function, it shows. I was wondering if anyone was able to make the two coexist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an issue where if the last item was deleted, the `DZNEmptyDataSet` wouldn't reappear. I was able to get it working by subclassing `RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource`

```
final class MyRxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<S: AnimatableSectionModelType>: RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<S> {

private var currentItemsCount = 0

var isEmpty: Bool {
    return currentItemsCount == 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, observedEvent: Event<[S]>) {
    super.tableView(tableView, observedEvent: observedEvent)
    switch observedEvent {
    case let .next(events):
        guard let lastEvent = events.last else { return }
        currentItemsCount = lastEvent.items.count
    default: break
    }
  }
}
```

Then return the dataSource.isEmpty property in `DZNEmptyDataSetDelegate`

```
func emptyDataSetShouldDisplay(_ scrollView: UIScrollView!) -> Bool {
    return dataSource.isEmpty
}
```

Originally, in the delegate method I was returning the `number of rows for section 0`. The delay between when the original `DataSource` sent deleted events and when the tableView registered the changes kept the number above zero when `tableView.reloadEmptyDataSet()` was called.

Now it is called automatically and is given the proper shouldDisplay value.

Answer (score 0):

I mixed `RxSwift` with `DZNEmptyDataSet` and it's fine.
Try code below:

```
let arrayVariable = Variable([])

arrayVariable
    .asObservable()
    .bindTo(newsTableView.rx.items) { tableView, row, item in
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCellIdentifier", for: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0))
        return cell
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

You have to customize your implementation with appropriate *cell* and of course assign some real data to *arrayVariable*.

Comment: yeah, it didnt work when binding the table to an rxdatasource. i guess its rxdatasource that its not compatible with. I had to put an observable on the table being empty or not, and if it is call refreshemptydataset.